# GSAP tween not working correctly. Set duration has no effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, gsap

I am trying out the **GSAP** animation library. According to the [basic docs](https://greensock.com/jump-start-js#basic-tween) the syntax for getting a tween up and running is:

```
TweenLite.to( [target object], [duration in seconds], [destination values] )
```

So I have tried a really simple tween based on jQuery's hover event:

```
$('.contact-item').hover(function(){
    TweenLite.to(this,4,{background:'#671B4B'});
},function(){
    TweenLite.to(this,4,{background:'#FFFFFF'});
});
```

Oddly, the background does change to the correct color, but it tweens instantly instead of over the course of 4 seconds as I have specified in the second argument.

I did check to make sure the duration is in seconds not milliseconds. It's in the docs I linked to. I also made sure that I am using **`TweenLite`** and not **`TweenMax`**. I am using **`jQuery`** but I do not see any conflicts or errors in the console. I have also made sure that the **`CSSPlugin`** is included in my fiddle below.

Any help is appreciated. [here](http://jsfiddle.net/5w37kh2j/1/) is the fiddle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing `background` to `backgroundColor` should fix your problem. [[Link](https://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/GSAP/Plugins/CSSPlugin/)].

Comment: Hey that did work! I knew to camel case the CSS key but I did not know that GSAP would not parse the shorthand "background". Thanks a bunch!